# Stacked RFID tags

Tags: rfid

If I have a stack of papers each with an RFID tag in the corner, is there a way for an RFID reader to only read the RFID tag on the top piece of paper, without the RFID tags below interfering?

Comment: probably not.  can you use barcode instead?

Comment: No, because I don't want it to require line of sight. If I put the RFID tag in a different orientation than the one below it, that can work, but the problem is it needs to work with a stack of 50 papers.

Comment: yes there is a way .... put all the sheets into an RF shielded bag except the top sheet

Comment: Explain your application a bit if you can.  Why must the papers be in an aligned stack at time of scanning if you only wish to read the top tag?  Is this for a human user or would it benefit from automation?

Answer (score 1):

OK I said it was impossible. Now I'll tell you how to do it!

Paper HF RFID tags are a resonant circuit with a printed coil and a two plate capacitor
[image: Shown here with a paperclip of unknown size for scale!]

to make these directional you need to increase the size of the lower plate of the capacitor such that when such a tag is above another tag of the same type the lower plate couples with the tag belows lower and upper plates de-tuning it. thus leaving only the uppermost tagke in a working state.

[image: anti-stacking paper tag]

the large green circle is the top capacitor plate, the large brown circle is the lower plate, the slots reduce the shorted turn effect of such a large plate inside the coil

the small circle is a join between the brown and green layers

Because the capacitance effect needs to work through a sheet of paper the capacitopr will probably need a fairly thick dielectric for the effect to be significant, or perhaps a foil
sticker can be placed on the back of the paper.

Comment: The problmem of how to get this deck of cards onto the blackjack table is left to the reader

Comment: I doubt this would work. In addition to the capacitive coupling you also have magnetic coupling which would detune all the tags.